# How To Setup Post-Commit Email in VisualSVN

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, visualsvn-server, post-commit

I am trying to configure the built-in post-commit hook for VisualSVN Server.  I configured the post-commit script directly through VisualSVN Server Manager and it is as follows:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
    --from aaron@posscribble.com --to aaron@posscribble.com ^
    --smtp-server mail.posscribble.com
```

The post-commit fails with the following error message:

[image: Post-Commit Error]

Can someone help me understand why VisualSVN is referencing the C:\Development\Source\format path?  I have also tried replacing the environment variable (i.e. %VISUALSVN_SERVER%) with the direct path to the directory where VisualSVNServerHooks.exe is located to no avail.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your repository stored in C:\Development\ directory? Is it's name "Source"?

Comment: Believe it or not, after much searching someone recommended taking the parenthesis off the first argument so that it is just %1 and that solved the problem.  The path to the repository has spaces in it and I copied the script right off of VisualSVN Server documentation.  Anyways, that solved the issue.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote it then. I'm trying to "optimize rep' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scouring web forums someone recommended taking the parenthesis off the first argument even though the path to the repository has parenthesis in it so that it is just %1 and that solved the problem. The working VisualSVN post-commit script is below:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification %1 -r %2 ^
    --from aaron@posscribble.com --to aaron@posscribble.com ^
    --smtp-server mail.posscribble.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite irrelevant to the post-commit hook script. The error states that the repository lacks "format" file. It's expected that this file exists and [contains the format number of this filesystem](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure). So does the file exist?

If the file is missing, you can't do anything with the repository: you can't access the repository with Subversion client, can't run `svnadmin` commands and it's expected that the hook scripts fail (at least on latest SVN / VisualSVN Server versions).

The easiest way to solve the issue would be to take format file from another repository and copy it to "C:\Development\Source\". However you must ensure that the copied file has correct format number for the `Source` repository.

Comment: I solved the issue...see my comment above.  How should I close this post?  Create my own answer?

Comment: @Grasshopper create your own answer and accept it as the correct one :)